# Read from string and convert to Dynamic

Tags: haskell

I want to implement a function as below:

```
readToDyn::String->Maybe Dynamic
readToDyn x = readMaybe x >>= pure . toDyn
```

It convert a string to a specific type and then pack it to `Dynamic` type. The problem is that the type variable `a` in `readMaybe::Read a =>String->Maybe a` is **Ambiguous** and so it cannot be compiled.

Does have any way to ignore such **Ambiguous** when defined above function so that I can specify the type when call `fromDynamic`?  like

```
do x <- readToDyn
   fromDynamic x::Maybe Int
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is to just store the `String`, and parse it later on.

When you build the `Dynamic` value, there is no way to parse a string without knowing which type will be demanded later on, when `fromDynamic` is used. No useful pre-processing can be performed at this stage.

In principle, you could use a universally qualified type such as:

```
data Parsed = Parsed { parse :: forall a . Read a => Maybe a }

readToDyn :: String -> Dynamic
readToDyn x = toDyn (Parsed (readMaybe x))

-- ...
do let x = readToDyn someString
   -- ...
   use (parse (fromDynamic x) :: Maybe Int)
```

But this is pointlessly complex. Note `readToDyn` does not return a `Maybe Dynamic` since here there is no way to know if parsing will fail later on, reflecting that we do not know we will need to parse an `Int`.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative interpretation of your question: you want to determine what concrete type to use *from the string*. I.e. `readToDyn "4"` should give an integer, `readToDyn "True"` should give a boolean, etc. etc.. Such an approach will always be incomplete, but if you only need it to work for a limited collection of types then this is ok. Basically, you'd do this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import Control.Applicative ((<|>))

readToDyn :: String -> Maybe Dynamic
readToDyn s = (toDyn @Integer <$> readMaybe s)
          <|> (toDyn @Bool <$> readMaybe s)
          <|> ...
```

More elegant/extensible way of doing this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, DataKinds, TypeInType
           , AllowAmbiguousTypes, UnicodeSyntax, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Kind (Type)

class DynRead (ts :: [Type]) where
   readToDyn :: String -> Maybe Dynamic

instance DynRead ('[]) where
   readToDyn _ = Nothing
instance ∀ h t . (Read h, Typeable h, DynRead t) => DynRead (h ': t) where
   readToDyn s = toDyn @h <$> readMaybe s
                    <|> readToDyn @t s
```

```
> readToDyn @'[Int, Double] "3.14"
Just <<Double>>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, RankNTypes, UnicodeSyntax #-}
```

`Dynamic` is an *existential* type. This means, every wrapped value actually belongs to a concrete “static type”, you just don't know which before inspecting it.

```
data Dynamic where
    Dynamic :: ∀ a. TypeRep a -> a -> Dynamic
       -- i.e. ∀ a.(TypeRep a -> a -> Dynamic)
```

This uses a *for all* quantor, but it would arguably better to understand it with an existential one (not currently legal in Haskell):

```
data Dynamic where
    Dynamic :: (∃ a. (TypeRep a, a)) -> Dynamic
```

(Note that the quantor is now in the constructor's *argument*, when before it was around the entire constructor).

What you want is rather a *universal* type instead, i.e. one where the underlying value itself doesn't know what type it will be but can adapt for whatever is needed at the call site. This is expressed with a universal quantor in the argument:

```
data AnyReadable where
  AnyReadable :: (∀ a. Read a => a) -> AnyReadable
```

However, this doesn't really work for `Read`, at least not with `String -> Maybe AnyReadable`, because you need to know what type you want to read it as before finding out whether there is a parse error.